# Disable hydration in Sapper

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, svelte, sapper

I was testing Sapper and got stuck with complex TweenMax page transitions I'm used to do when working with BarbaJS or HighwayJS, so I'm wondering is there's a way to disable hydration in Sapper so that I can only have the SSR website I can bend to my will.

If there's a way, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure — just delete the code in `src/client.js` that starts the app

Comment: So simple that I didn't think about doing that. Thank you very much!