# How to disable SPA-like navigation in Sapper?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

i want to disable SPA-like navigation in Sapper (kindly please let's not jump into discussion if it's a right thing to do). I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/58645471/205747 recommendation and just commented out everything in client.js.

This gives the following requirements of mine satisfied:

```
[x] HTTP navigation;  
[x] HTML composition achieved with svelte components;  
[x] CSS classed from all components are extracted to single place;
```

But the last requirement is not satisfied:

```
[ ] DOM manipulation logic is handled by svelte;
```

So the question is - how would I disable SPA-like navigation in favor of HTTP navigation and yet the dom manipulation would be handled by sapper/svelte?

To give another perspective - I'd love svelte/sapper to behave like reacts' renderToStaticMarkup for html and yet have the dom manipulation in a good-old jquery approach, just handled by svelte.

edit: I use https://github.com/beewee22/sapper-template-typescript template as a starting point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sapper doesn't support that out-of-the-box today. You'd have to build a custom version of Sapper. You might be able to accomplish that by commenting out `init_router` in `rnutime/src/app/app.ts`

Comment: Ben, many thanks! Will create a feature request then in the Sapper github repo.

Comment: Created a ticket here: https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/1614 .